# Why does adding a middlename omit authors in References list

Tags: bibtex, jabref

I cite a specific paper for my publication. The problem is when I add the middle initial of one author, the entire author list gets omitted from the references list, as shown in the image. I omitted the middle initial in the second example.
[image]

Any clues as to why?

Comment: Dashes usually indicate a duplication of the author. Is it the same author in the entry *above* the one displaying the dashes?

Comment: Yes it is, that makes sense then! If you write the answer I'll accept it right away :)

Comment: I think the essential point is covered by the answer I've duped to: dashes = repeated identical author(s).